# PHP - Bootstrap modals

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

So I have piece of code

```
<a href='#tos-modal' class='modal-trigger'><li class='valign-wrapper' style='padding-left: 1em; padding-right: 1em;'>
```

But it's not working for me. I had my files on Localhost and all were working perfectly, now I uploaded to webhost and not working :(. How could I fix it without changing that code?

```
<div class="modal" id="tos-modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4>Terms of Service Agreement</h4>  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer row valign-wrapper">
              <div class="col s10"><input type="checkbox" id="tos-accept"><label for="tos-accept">I accept the Terms of Service and I am at least 18 years of age.</label></div>
              <a href="/?login" id="login-accepted-tos" class="btn green waves-effect waves-light col s2 disabled">Sign In</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: you tagged as php but code to support the question. Plus, one line of code doesn't cut it.

Comment: You don't give enough code. Please post the HTML for the modal you are trying to open. Did you include the bootstrap javascript? Any console errors?

Comment: I edited first post. I don't see any errors.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php that's all I can say.

Comment: As @Keeleon asked, can you verify that the bootstrap javascript is included, and not pointing to localhost?

Comment: These

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Also, If I do "Inspect Element" -> Sources, then it shows css, images folder. But on hosting it doesn't show them.